# detecting http vs rmi traffic in weblogic cluster

Tags: weblogic

is there a way to detect what containers are making RMI calls inside of a weblogic cluster?

I have apps inside of a weblogic containers in a cluster where some make http calls and some use RMI. I want to see which ones are using RMI so that I can rebuild those apps using http.